# Keyword list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in JavaScript.This is my college assignment. I did it, but I don't understand why the code doesn't work. The final project should have a sidebar as Keyword List. The first screenshot is what I got, the second one is what I should get. I already added the related id s in HTML and CSS files. Thanks for your helping in advance.

here is my JS code.

```
"use strict";
window.addEventListener("load", findKeyWords);
window.addEventListener("load", makeKeyStyles);
//Locate the keywords in the article indicated by the <dfn> tag
//and add those keywords in alphabetical order to a keyword box.
function findKeyWords() {
  var keywords = document.createElement("aside");
  var mainHeading = document.createElement("h1");
  var headingText = document.createTextNode("Keywords List");
  var orderList = document.createElement("ol");
  mainHeading.appendChild(headingText);
  keywords.appendChild(mainHeading);
  keywords.appendChild(orderList);
  var keyWordElems = document.getElementById("doc").querySelectorAll("dfn");
  var keyWords = keyWordElems.length;
  for (var i = 0; keyWordElems.length; i++) {
    keyWords += keyWordElems[i];
    var linkID = replaceWS(keyWords);
    keyWordElems[i] = keyWords + "_" + linkID;
  }
  keyWords.shadowRoot(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < keyWords.length; i++) {
    var keyWordListItem = document.createElement("li");
    var keyWordLink = document.createElement("a");
    keyWordLink.innerHTML = keyWords[i];
    linkID = replace(keyWords);
    keyWordLink.setAttribute("id", keyWords[i] + linkID);
    keyWordListItem.appendChild(KeyWordLink);
    orderList.appendChild(keyWordListItem);
  }
  keywords.firstChild("article#doc");
}
//Create an embedded style sheet for the keyword box.
function makeKeyStyles() {
  var embeddedStyles = document.createElement("style");
  document.head.appendChild(embeddedStyles);
  document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1].insertRule("aside#keywords { \
 border: 3px solid rgb(101, 101, 101); \
 float: right; \
 margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px; \
 padding: 10px; \
 width: 320px; \
 }", 0);

  document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1].insertRule("aside#keywords h1 { \
font-size: 2em; \
margin: 5px; \
text-align: center; \
}", 1);

  document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1].insertRule("aside#keywords ol { \
font-size: 20px; \
font-size: 1.2em; \
}", 2);

  document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1].insertRule("aside#keywords ol li { \
line-height: 1.5em; \
}", 3);

  document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1].insertRule("aside#keywords ol li a { \
color: rgb(101, 101, 101); \
text-decoration: none; \
}", 4);
}
/* Supplied Functions */
function replaceWS(textStr) {
  var revText = textStr.replace(/\s+/g, "_");
  return revText;
}
```

[image: This is what I am getting]
[image: This is what it should look like]

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the problem is? Are there any errors? What is the output, and what were you expecting instead?

Comment: I think the last pic is the expected output but you are getting the first one...? Is that right ... ?

Comment: Why does your CSS rules have a `\\` as a line break? Remove them and keep your CSS rules in one unbroken line.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007359/extract-highlighted-keywords-from-text-with-javascript-and-display-them-in-side

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to accumulate all your keywords into an array, in plain text, instead of what you are doing at the moment AND later adding styles + required html tags around it. That way you don't have to `+=` into `keyWords +=` as you are doing at the moment.

I suggest this since some of your logic to tag and style it assumes so (IMO). Once, you construct this array you could use a `.map()` to add tags+style AND then `.join()` to get what you need.

Let me know if that makes sense. Happy to answer further questions ...

Answer (score 0):

## List of Discrepancies

1. never gave `<aside>` an `id='keywords'`
2. `keyWords` declared as the number of `<dfns>` (Let's say there's 7)
3. `keyWords += keyWordElems` (ex. 7 + `<dfn>`) ???
4. `var linkID = replaceWS(7)`; (ex. 7)
5. `<dfn>` = 7 + "_" + 7; ???
6. Certain conditions must be met in order to use `.shadowRoot()`, but even if these conditions were met, `.shadowRoot()` would be useless at this point. (ex. `.shadowRoot(Not a Function)`)
7. `(function(a, b) { return a-b})` should be `arrayOfkeyWords.sort()`
8. `keyWordLink.innerHTML = keyWords[i]`; ??? (ex. `<a><dfn></dfn></a>`)
9. `linkID = replace(keyWords);` (ex. 7 = Not a Function) -- This is the signature of the `replace()` method: `string.replace(regex, replacement)`.
10. `keyWordLink.setAttribute("id", keyWords[i] + linkID);` ??? -- (ex. `<a id="<dfn></dfn>7">`)
11. `keywords.firstChild("article#doc")`; -- does nothing
12. You should never assign styles like this, just create classes in an external stylesheet (ex. `<link href='https://example.com/path/to/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>`)
    The `\\` line breaks are unnecessary and these styles would fail silently because `#keywords` doesn't exist and the invalid syntax from the `\\`

    `"aside#keywords { \ 
    border: 3px solid rgb(101, 101, 101); \
    float: right; \
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px; \
    padding: 10px; \
    width: 320px; \
    }", 0);`

---

### Demo

```js
var rules = `
aside#keywords {border: 3px solid rgb(101, 101, 101); float: right; margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px; padding: 10px; width: 320px;} 
aside#keywords h1 {font-size: 2em; margin: 5px; text-align: center; }
aside#keywords ol {font-size: 1.2em;}
aside#keywords ol li {line-height: 1.5em;}
aside#keywords ol li a {color: rgb(101, 101, 101); text-decoration: none;}`;

function injectStyles(rules) {
  var head = document.querySelector('head');
  var kS = document.getElementById('keyStyles');
  if (!kS) {
    head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<style id="keyStyles">${rules}</style>`);
  } else {
    kS.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', rules);
  }
}

function keyWordList(e) {
  var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var keywords = document.createElement("aside");
  var mainHeading = document.createElement("h1");
  var headingText = document.createTextNode("Keywords List");
  var orderList = document.createElement("ol");

  mainHeading.appendChild(headingText);
  keywords.appendChild(mainHeading);
  keywords.appendChild(orderList);
  docFrag.appendChild(keywords);
  keywords.id = 'keywords';

  var keyWordDFN = document.querySelectorAll("dfn");
  var keyWordQty = keyWordDFN.length;
  var keyWords = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < keyWordQty; i++) {
   keyWords.push(keyWordDFN[i].textContent.toLowerCase());
  }
  keyWords = keyWords.sort();

  for (let t = 0; t < keyWordQty; t++) {
    var keyWordListItem = document.createElement("li");
    var keyWordLink = document.createElement("a");
    keyWordLink.textContent = keyWords[t];
    keyWordLink.href = "#/";
    keyWordListItem.appendChild(keyWordLink);
    orderList.appendChild(keyWordListItem);
  }
  document.getElementById('DOC').prepend(docFrag);
  return injectStyles(rules);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", keyWordList);
```

```css
main {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<main id='DOC'>
  <p><dfn>Lorem</dfn> ipsum dolor sit amet, <dfn>consectetur</dfn> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <dfn>magna</dfn> aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation <dfn>ullamco</dfn> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in <dfn>reprehenderit</dfn> in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint <dfn>occaecat</dfn> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</main>
```